# how to call a method from same object in different packages in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I have different  packages like com.pack01 , com.pac02 so on.. for one of my object A , i need to this object everytime to create something based on version parameter.

E.g If I have version "01" then it should create that object from com.pack01 ..If I have version "02" then it should create that object from com.pack02so on and so forth.

Once i get this object , i will call one create() method from it.

I am thinking of using a factory pattern here but confused how do i get particular object of the type from it as i cannot return an Object everytime because i need to perform further operation of create() on  it ?

Is there any other way i can achieve the expected functionality ?

**Current sample code :**

```
A a = new  A();
a.create();
```

**Expected code:**

```
if(version.equals("01"))
com.pack01.A a = new com.pack01.A();
a.create();
```

I need to do it in a better way as per the versions .can anybody suggest a better practice as i am new design patterns in java?

Comment: Factory or Template would be an appropraite pattern. That said, more towards [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, you should program all of those `A` classes to a common interface, and use that interface in the rest of your code. Specifically to versioning with java (a bit outside of a software design pattern): build tools like maven allow you to have modules, which would allow you to implement those classes _per version_, and then compile them speculatively depending on what version you're targetting.

Comment: Just to clarify version is parameter which i will get from front end , i  want to get object of class A as per the version defined from front end

Comment: In that case, factory or template would work fine in your case. Rather than a large if-else statement, you'd make use of something like a `HashMap` to look up what kind of class would accept/operate on your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Factory{
    // first solution
    public Object getInstanseOfA(String version){
          if(version ==' ---  '){}
          else if (version == '111'){}
    }
    // second solution
    public static String version='1.0';
    public Object getInstanseOfA(){
          if(this.version ==' ---  '){}
          else if (this.version == '111'){}
    }
}
```

I don't know if that solves your problem! tell me

Comment: at the very least, make the `public static String version` `final` as well, otherwise it could be changed anywhere in your application. As it is `static`, it should be accessed via the classname, not via `this` - use `Factory.version` or remove `static`.

Comment: thanks for your reply Yahya Shqair .appreciate :) but this still does not solve my problem as this factory class will return me an Object which i need to cast again to A and then  call create method , wanted a generic approach without if else branching ..

Comment: i think here you need to make a parent class for all A that contains the 'create' function and each A class in a package need to extends it in order to avoid casting @yzone

Comment: @Hulk it depends on what he needed, static can be accessed via classname or this ! all point in the same value

Comment: @Hulk that A class autogenerated class like a jaxb class from xsd like ObjectFactory class , so i want to instantiate particular objectfactory in diff packages as per version  given by front end ..need a way to dyanically rather than traditional if else

Comment: @yzone after 8 months of experience haha I think you should go with Reflection to call your method.